# Preenchimento de vetor par-impar C

Tags: c, array

Bom pessoal to travado num probleminha aqui vou colocar o enunciado aqui:
"Neste problema você deverá ler 15 valores colocá-los em 2 vetores conforme estes valores forem pares ou ímpares. Só que o tamanho de cada um dos dois vetores é de 5 posições. Então, cada vez que um dos dois vetores encher, você deverá imprimir todo o vetor e utilizá-lo novamente para os próximos números que forem lidos. Terminada a leitura, deve-se imprimir o conteúdo que restou em cada um dos dois vetores, imprimindo primeiro os valores do vetor impar. Cada vetor pode ser preenchido tantas vezes quantas for necessário." 
A parte final do reset do vetor para ser preenchido e o que ta complicando meu código esta assim no momento:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int par[5];
    int impar[5];
    int n,i;
    while(i==0){
        par[i]=0;
        impar[i]=0;
        for(i=0;i<15;i++){
            scanf("%d",&n);
            if(n%2==0){
                for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                    par[i]=n;
                    printf("par[%d] = %d\n",i,par[i]);
               }
            }else{
                for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                    impar[i]=n;
                    printf("impar[%d] = %d\n",i,impar[i]);
                }
            }

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa buscar modularizar seu problema em diferentes funções para não perder o fio da meada. Para inicialização do vetor, basta usar [Designated Initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) do C99 para preencher os vetores com valor inicial 0 em todas as posições ou iterar pelo vetor setando o valor manualmente. Seu problema parece bem trivial, então tomei a liberdade de oferecer uma solução priorizando estruturas simples. Faça suas adaptações caso ache necessário:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int VET_SIZE = 15;
const int PARIMP_SIZE = 5;

void show (int* vect) { 
 for (int i = 0; i < PARIMP_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", vect[i]);
    }
  puts("");
}

void reset (int* vect) {
 for(int i = 0; i < PARIMP_SIZE; i++) {
       vect[i] = 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {

   int PAR_N[PARIMP_SIZE]; 
   int IMPAR_N[PARIMP_SIZE];
   int current, PAR_POS  = 0, IMPAR_POS = 0;

   reset(PAR_N);
   reset(IMPAR_N);

  for (int i = 0; i < VET_SIZE; i++)  {
    printf ("%d - Entre com um valor: ", (i+1));
    scanf(" %d",&current);

    if (current % 2 == 0) {

       if (PAR_POS < 5) { 
        PAR_N[PAR_POS] = current;
        PAR_POS++;
       } else {
        PAR_POS = 0;
        PAR_N[PAR_POS] = current;
        puts("Vetor PAR - Cheio");
        show(PAR_N);
        reset(PAR_N);
      }

    } else {

      if (IMPAR_POS < 5) {
        IMPAR_N[IMPAR_POS] = current;
        IMPAR_POS++;
      } else { 
        IMPAR_POS = 0;
        IMPAR_N[IMPAR_POS] = current;
        puts("Vetor IMPAR - Cheio");
        show(IMPAR_N);
        reset(IMPAR_N);
     }

    }
  }

    puts("Vetor IMPAR");
    show(IMPAR_N);
    puts("Vetor PAR");
    show(PAR_N);

    return 0;
}
```

A função **show()** apenas varre o vetor e dá um print nos elementos.

A função **reset()** apenas reseta os elementos de um vetor.

**main()** utiliza dois inteiros auxiliares para indexar os respectivos vetores para ir realizando a contagem a medida que os vetores são preenchidos. Quando um deles atinge a quantidade esperada o vetor é exibido na tela, seu conteúdo é setado em zero e o inteiro correspondente ao vetor volta para a posição zero. No final do programa, ele exibe ambos os vetores no estado atual.

Comment: Calma, calma, ta muito avançado para min isso, nossa

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver aqui esta o codigo certo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int par[5], j, impar[5], i, P = 0, I = 0, x;

void main(void) {
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            par[P] = x;
            P++;
            if (P == 5) {
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    printf("par[%d] = %d\n", j, par[j]);
                }
                P = 0;
            }
        } else {
            impar[I] = x;
            I++;
            if (I == 5) {
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    printf("impar[%d] = %d\n", j, impar[j]);
                }
                I = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < I; j++) {
        printf("impar[%d] = %d\n", j, impar[j]);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < P; j++) {
        printf("par[%d] = %d\n", j, par[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O uso do operador % (módulo) pode facilitar o controle de quando cada vetor ficou cheio e portanto deve ser impresso, mantendo a contagem de todos os números, pares ou ímpares, já encontrados.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int par[5], impar[5], qtd_par=0, qtd_impar=0, i, j, x;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            par[qtd_par%5] = x;
            qtd_par++;
            if (qtd_par%5 == 0) {
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    printf("par[%d] = %d\t", j, par[j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        } else {
            impar[qtd_impar%5] = x;
            qtd_impar++;
            if (qtd_impar%5 == 0) {
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    printf("impar[%d] = %d\t", j, impar[j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < qtd_impar%5; j++) {
        printf("impar[%d] = %d\t", j, impar[j]);
    }
    printf("\nQuantidade total de ímpares: %d\n\n", qtd_impar);
    for (j = 0; j < qtd_par%5; j++) {
        printf("par[%d] = %d\n", j, par[j]);
    }
    printf("\nQuantidade total de pares: %d\n", qtd_par);
    return 0;
}
```